# rsa 2048 implementation using swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, wampserver

i am developing a desktop application using swings,where user sign in,register, and send messages.i planned to implement RSA 2048,Where key exchange,encryption while sending and decryption after receiving mail takes place.i  don't know how to do for message encryption and decryption.i know RSA logic to implement for integers,and even for strings as a whole program but have no idea doing in seperate module

how we can implement mail sending using socket???

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail-138606.html).